# The command 'pip install Somepackage' does not work on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pip, ubuntu-20.04

I have **Ubuntu 20.04** installed.
I have `python3.8` and `python3-pip` installed.
however when executing `pip install SomePackage` I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==7.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip-7.1.0-py3.8.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 217, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip-7.1.0-py3.8.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 216, in main
    with self._build_session(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip-7.1.0-py3.8.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 68, in _build_session
    session = PipSession(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip-7.1.0-py3.8.egg/pip/download.py", line 316, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip-7.1.0-py3.8.egg/pip/download.py", line 92, in user_agent
    zip(["name", "version", "id"], platform.linux_distribution()),
AttributeError: module 'platform' has no attribute 'linux_distribution'
```

Comment: look up this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58758447/how-to-fix-module-platform-has-no-attribute-linux-distribution-when-instal)

Comment: [Refer to this answer for the fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60046826/13261176)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using python 3.x.x. That's why you should use pip3.

Try like this:

```
pip3 install SomePackage
```

use this if pip3 doesn't load:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

You can also update using this:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, asi mismo lo solucione. Sld