# pip3 error : AttributeError: module 'platform' has no attribute 'linux_distribution'? (ubuntu 20.04 with python 3.8)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip

I think i have messed up some python files when installing some packages in a requirement.txt file

now i get these errors when trying to install or uninstall anything:

for example when trying to uninstall matplotlib without sudo using pip3 uninstall matplotlib (even tho i never had to use sudo to uninstall anything before) :

```
Found existing installation: matplotlib 3.3.1
Uninstalling matplotlib-3.3.1:
  Would remove:
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/matplotlib-3.3.1-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg
Proceed (y/n)? y
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 788, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/matplotlib-3.3.1-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg' -> '/tmp/pip-uninstall-nw393b36'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 228, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/uninstall.py", line 89, in run
    uninstall_pathset = req.uninstall(
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 686, in uninstall
    uninstalled_pathset.remove(auto_confirm, verbose)
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 394, in remove
    moved.stash(path)
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 283, in stash
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 352, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 800, in move
    rmtree(src)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 715, in rmtree
    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 672, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 670, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    os.unlink(entry.name, dir_fd=topfd)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'pylab.py'
```

When trying with sudo :

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/commands/uninstall.py", line 46, in run
    with self._build_session(options) as session:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 66, in _build_session
    session = PipSession(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 321, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 93, in user_agent
    zip(["name", "version", "id"], platform.linux_distribution()),
AttributeError: module 'platform' has no attribute 'linux_distribution'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('pip==20.3.dev0', 'console_scripts', 'pip3')())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 217, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 242, in main
    with self._build_session(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 66, in _build_session
    session = PipSession(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 321, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 93, in user_agent
    zip(["name", "version", "id"], platform.linux_distribution()),
AttributeError: module 'platform' has no attribute 'linux_distribution'
```

How can i fix this? i am using ubuntu 20.04 and i heard uninstalling python3.8 is a big no no since many system files use it, so what should i do?

tried many suggestion on similar questions like this  and it didn't work:

[How to fix "module 'platform' has no attribute 'linux_distribution'" when installing new packages with Python3.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58758447/how-to-fix-module-platform-has-no-attribute-linux-distribution-when-instal)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "module 'platform' has no attribute 'linux\_distribution'" when installing new packages with Python3.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58758447/how-to-fix-module-platform-has-no-attribute-linux-distribution-when-instal)

Comment: @OlvinRoght nope, tried that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.8 removed some stuff. I solved my problems with pip (specifically pip install) by installing pip with curl

What worked for me was:
cd ~/Downloads
Downloading get-pip.py

> curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py

Then running it with python 3.8:

> python3.8 get-pip.py

Solved it for me.