# Installed Conda but it is corrupted when trying to run

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

```
conda
An unexpected error has occurred.
Please consider posting the following information to the
conda GitHub issue tracker at:

    https://github.com/conda/conda/issues



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adithyan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 626, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)

 
    distinfo = platform.linux_distribution()
AttributeError: module 'platform' has no attribute 'linux_distribution'
```

this is the error im getting. re-installed yet same issue persist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "module 'platform' has no attribute 'linux\_distribution'" when installing new packages with Python3.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58758447/how-to-fix-module-platform-has-no-attribute-linux-distribution-when-instal)

Comment: How did you install Conda? The location it is loading the package from implies you used `pip install --user conda`, which is not a supported way for installing. In general, Conda does not work well with any user-level Python installations.